# Why does this jQuery call fail in Firefox?

Tags: jquery

I have created a link with a JavaScript call using animate and scrolltop. It works perfectly well everywhere, but in Firefox it navigates to a whole other page. Any ideas?

```
<a href="javascript:$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#PAGETAG').offset().top  + -500 }, 200);
    $('#alertify-ok').trigger('click');"> [my text] </a>
```

A proper outcome in Chrome and IE, the alertify box disappears and the page scrolls to my tag.

Comment: Inline scripting is typically a bad idea.  Especially when you are doing multiple things.  Extract it to a script tag, add the binding in there, do your work, and increase your readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: Add `return false` to the end of that javascript

Comment: @duncan Please don't answer in the comments. Use the answer box, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false` to the end of that javascript

Answer (score 0):

Extract your logic from the inline scripting.  You can add a class to generalize this if you are doing this for multiple elements.  You can also use a data element to specify which one to scroll to.  Then all you have to do in the event handler is cancel the click event, before doing your logic.

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTargetAndAlert" data-target="PAGETAG"> [my text] </a>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.scrollToTargetAndAlert').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetSelector = '#'+ e.target.getAttribute('data-target');

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(targetSelector).offset().top  + -500
            }, 200);
            $('#alertify-ok').trigger('click');
        });
    });
</script>
```